# Excel - Knowing 5 first digits, find a path to path a file using VBA and Regex

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I'm working in an environment with always follow this hierarchy:

```
F:\Client Documents\"JobCategory"\"JobNumber-ClientName"\Estimate
```

Being:

- **JobNumber** always the 2 digits year follow by 3 sequential digits eg: 15255 (255th job of 2015 )
- **JobCategory** is used to separate jobs by hundreds, eg, the above job # will be found in folder 15200
- **ClientName is the problem**, where obviously can be any name...

So at the moment, I have to type correctly the whole job number and name and trough excel I extract the job category and so on... but in order to automatize some other macros. Is there any way where the script finds (or search/match) the first 5 digits and if it match, use that name as a path?

Eg. if I know job # 15255,  F:\Client Documents\15200\15255-JohnSmith or 
\15255-JohnSnow will be a match?

If relevant... the VBA script I have so far to save my workbook is:

```
Dim JobCat As String, JobDetails As String
 JobCat = Sheet12.Range("P4").Text
  JobNumber = Sheet12.Range("P5").Text

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "F:\Client Documents\" & JobCat & "\" & JobDetails & "\Estimate.xlsm" _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Where in `P5` I type the hole JobNumber-ClientName and `P4` extract its Number category.

Any help, even to clarify if it's possible will be helpful

Comment: Please clarify: 1) What is the exact input string, 2) What is the exact output? Have a [look here](https://regex101.com/r/tU8pE0/1), please fork or update to show what you have and what you need.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba for a way to loop through files. See the second (not accepted) answer for a very speedy way.  You *could* use a regex, but this method is much simpler and faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Dir` function to get the first Folder that matches your search string (if you run `Dir` without parameters after the first execution, you will get the next Folder that matches the search string)

This should work for you:

```
Public Sub saveMe()
Dim JobCat As String, JobDetails As String
Dim Path As String

JobCat = Sheet12.Range("P4").Text
JobNumber = Sheet12.Range("P5").Text

Path = Dir("F:\Client Documents\" & JobCat & "\" & JobDetails & "*", vbDirectory)

If Path <> "" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        Path & "\Estimate.xlsm" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your help, your script can find the name string but error 1004 is returning when try to save.  I am using:
     Path = Dir("C:\test\" & JobCat & "\" & JobNumber & "*", vbDirectory)
for test in my own pc, but when I run the macro, looks like after it finds the name, it points to my user\Documents directory. Precisely:
     C:\Users\diego\Documents\15116-Mr Smith\FF83F380
As you can see it finds correctly the JobNumber+Client Name "15116-Mr Smith" but is trying to save on my documents.. also, don't know where it got that "FF83F380" from ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Dorian , had to modify a little bit it's path so my final script is:

```
Public Sub saveMe()
Dim JobCat As String, JobNumber As String
Dim Path As String

JobCat = Sheet1.Range("A5").Text
JobNumber = Sheet1.Range("A4").Text

Path = Dir("C:\test\" & JobCat & "\" & JobNumber & "*", vbDirectory)

If Path <> "" Then
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\test\" & JobCat & "\" & Path & "\Estimate.xlsm" _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry, i didn't mind the function only returns the folder name, but not the entire path.